# Cell array to matrix conversion in matlab

Tags: arrays, regex, matlab, matrix, cell-array

I would like to covert three `<1xN cell>` (`A`, `B` and `C`) into a single `Nx3` matrix. Could someone help me with this?

```
C={{1xN}; {1xN}; {1xN}};
```

where each `N` is a number in single quotes, e.g.

```
C = {{'123123' ,'12324', ....N times}; {'123123', '12324', ....N times}; {'123123', '12324' ,....N times}}
```

Since a couple of them mentioned about the ridiculous input, this is the reason for having it in the above form.

The three nested array of cells are the results of a regexp where my string and expression are both strings. Therefore I have the output of regexp as three cell arrays of row vectors. 
For e.g.

```
node_ids=regexp(nodes,'(?<=node id=")\d*','match');
```

I can use cat function and then use a str2double for all three cell arrays and finally form a matrix by cell2mat. 
For e.g.

```
node_ids=cat(1,node_ids{:});node_ids=str2double(node_ids);
```

But this takes more time and has more LOC. 
My question is can it be done with fewer lines of code?

I tried using the `cat` function but keep getting this error:

> Cannot support cell arrays containing cell arrays or objects.

Comment: Mind telling us what is *in* the cells?

Comment: C={{1xN}; {1xN}; {1xN}}; where each N is a number in single quotes(for ex. C = {{'123123' '12324' ....N times}; {'123123' '12324' ....N times}; {'123123' '12324' ....N times}}   hope this gives more clarity about the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input data is pretty bad.... why are you using a nested array of cells where each element is a string?

In any case, assuming `C` is your original input data, do this:

```
C = {{'123123' '12324'}; {'123123' '12324'}; {'123123' '12324'}};
out = cellfun(@(x) cellfun(@str2num, x, 'uni', 0), C, 'uni', 0);
out = cell2mat(cellfun(@cell2mat, out, 'uni', 0));
```

First line is some dummy data.  Next line first goes through every nested cell element over your cell array and converts the strings into numbers.  However, these are still in cell arrays.  As such, the next line converts each cell array in the nested cell into a matrix, then we merge all of the cells together into one final matrix.

We get:

```
>> out

out =

      123123       12324
      123123       12324
      123123       12324
```

Comment: "Pretty bad" is being nice!

Comment: Hey guys @IKavanagh , I have edited my question for using this type of input data. Also, I used the above method and i got the following error: Error using str2num (line 33)
Requires string or character array input. I used str2double instead and got no errors but instead got NaN values in my matrix. Any reason for this?

Comment: @EyesOfÖzil If you get that error with the above method then your input is malformed and not as described in the question or demoed in this answer. This answer works perfectly for me. Maybe you could post the specific data that is causing you an issue?

Comment: The input is this C = {{node_ids}; {node_a}; {node_b}}; where node_ids, node_a and node_b are the matches using regular expression. They are 1xN cells where each cell element is a string. Hope i am clear enough?

Comment: I guess the reason for that error is C = {{node_ids}; {node_a}; {node_b}}; is not the same as C = {{'123123' '12324'}; {'123123' '12324'}; {'123123' '12324'}};   sorry for the confusion created. @IKavanagh

Comment: Can you do `C = {node_ids; node_a; node_b};`?

Comment: thanks for the help guys! It worked fine with this C = {node_ids{:}; node_a{:}; node_b{:}};